# How can I install Nvidia driver 96.43.20? 

Tags: nvidia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the NVIDIA driver for a GeForce 6200?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82100/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-driver-for-a-geforce-6200)

To install the nvidia driver 96.43.20, you must exit the xserver.I used "sudo lightdm stop" to do this.  the screen then went blank and seemed to be showing a text editor which I don't know the commands for.  How do I get the nvidia run package to run in this environment.

trying to install this driver in ubuntu 11.10 has been very frustrating.  Has anyone posted a step by step installation guide to do this job.  If A person knew what they were doing I think it would be an easy job

Comment: See if any of the suggestions from this similar question can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82100/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-driver-for-a-geforce-6200/82482#82482

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method is to use jocky

[image: jocky]

In your menu System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers

If you wish to go the manual route, and install the binary from Nvidia manually, there is a detailed walk through on this page [Nvidia Manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual). This involves manually compiling the driver and is not advised. Be warned, if you do this, you will need to re-compile the nvidia driver with each kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-96`, or install it from your package manager.